# JPA Data with REST with multiple Repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

I am using Spring boot for JPA Data with Rest.   I am having a issue where only one repository is accessible when there is two.
For example:

> > localhostx.com:8080/abc --> loads fine
> >     localhostx.com:8080/xyz --> does not loads fine
> >     Stop and restart.
> >     localhostx.com:8080/abc --> does not loads fine
> >     localhostx.com:8080/xyz --> loads fine
> >     
> >     Has anybody had this kind of issues where you where using more than one repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can not put two resources on the same port. Place them on different ports, like:

> localhostx.com:8080/abc
>
> localhostx.com:8081/xyz